# In probability, what is the intuitive meaning of almost sure vs sure?

Tags: probability-theory, almost-everywhere

I am trying to understand what it means for some event $A$ to occur almost surely. I understand that the definition is that if $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a probability triple, then $A \in \mathcal{F}$ happens almost surely if $P(A) = 1$.

My understanding here is that this differs from occurring surely as there may exist events in which $\omega \notin A$, but that they happen with probability zero.

However, when I think of the example where we have a single roll of a die, the sample space being $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, it appears that $P(\omega\in \Omega) = 1$. However, this seems to only imply that this happens almost surely, that there are events which **could** occur, but happen with probability zero. I am not clear what those "null set" events are. Could someone tell me what those might be?

Comment: In the case of finite probability spaces, you can get only artificial examples like: one of the sides of a die is impossible to get. However, think of $[0,1]$ with the uniform probability distribution. Then getting, say $0.5$ is not impossible but its probability is zero.

Comment: In finite sample spaces, "almost sure" and "sure" are the same thing. "almost sure" is different only in infinite sample spaces. Like for example : infinite throw of a dice, $A$ is the event "obtain at least one $6$". $\mathbb P(A)=1$, but there are some $\omega$ which are not in $A$...

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS "Almost sure" is not equivalent to "sure", even in finite spaces. Take $\Omega = \{1,2 \}$ with $P(\{1\}) = 1 = 1 - P(\{2\})$. Then $\{1\}$ occurs almost surely but is not the sure event $\{ 1,2\}$.